# Difference of "as/like in the previous week"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, meaning-in-context, comparisons, as-like

Does the following correctly express the difference between "as" vs. "like" in this context?

> As in the previous week, Jimmy climbed the tree.

Jimmy climbed the tree and he also did it one week earlier.

> Jimmy climbed the tree like in the previous week.

Jimmy climbed the tree and he did it the same way one week earlier.

Comment: Why do you think there's a difference between *like* and *as* when used that way? What are you thinking this alleged difference is?  Ordering isn't going to matter here; consider *“Just like he did the week before, Jimmy climbed the tree”* as well as *“Jimmy climbed the tree today, just as he had done every week since Christmas.”* Those are all the same as both yours, which are also the same as each other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the subject has been covered exhaistively on EL&U, witness the comment supplying numerous duplicates.

Comment: I have read *all* the "duplicate" links (now deleted?) and *all* the blog links and it did not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second example is incorrect.  You could say "Jimmy climbed the tree like the way he did last week," or "Jimmy climbed a tree like the one he climbed last week."  A lot of native English speakers use "like" (incorrectly) where "as" is grammatically correct, and your last example sounds more like one of those cases. [Here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/like-vs-as/) is a fairly good explanation.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include any needed material from the link into your answer itself so that you don't make people chase elsewhere. It has to be stand-alone. Also, how can native speakers use it “incorrectly”? What does that even mean?

Comment: I'll try to improve the answer later tonight or tomorrow.  I won't reprise debates over grammar versus how people actually speak (which would far exceed the length of a comment, and, frankly, I drift across both sides of that fence), but in increasing numbers, people are using "like" where a grammarian will specify "as".  Some will grumble about an increase in illiteracy, and others that the language is evolving.  Either way, my point - admittedly made in haste - is that grammar says "like" is wrong in non-comparative context, while a lot of people keep using it that way.

Comment: What's a grammarian? Is that some special kind of linguist who thinks they get to tell other people how they're allowed to use language? Sounds sketchy to me. Sounds more like a mean kindergarten teacher than an actual linguist to me. Linguists study language; they're not cops.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but we do manage to follow enough rules to understand each other, even when the cops aren't around.  This is one of them - like most, used and ignored, as people see fit.